# What difficulties are there in evicting diplomats from their private residences as one would to anyone else?

Tags: eviction, diplomatic-immunity

Article 31(1)(a) of the Vienna convention on diplomatic relations allows for the receiving state to execute real actions on any private immovable property located on the land thereof, so where lies the reportedly insurmountable difficulties involved in evicting diplomats for even very egregious rental arrears?

Comment: There is no article 33(1)(a), but article 33 concerns social security provisions of the receiving state, so I suppose you intended to ask about a different article.

Answer (score 0):

### Diplomats are immune from local law

Unless waived, a person with diplomatic immunity is not answerable to local law. That means, a court or tribunal has no jurisdiction to issue or enforce an eviction notice if diplomatic immunity is raised as a defence. Even if one is granted, the police (or whoever) have no ability to enforce it.

So, the landlord issues the notice, when they try to enforce it, the court says “sorry, can’t help you.”